# rails with most nested models and cocoon gem;

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I have a rails4 app with nested model form. There is a `product` model that `has_many product_features`, `has_many product_usecases` and `has_many product_competitors`.

Everything works fine except when I load the page only the first nested model (product_features) will be visible. How can I also make one row visible for the other 2 models on page load?

UPDATE:

I have no js code yet for the form.

_form.html.erb

```
<div class="well product-well">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <%= f.fields_for :product_features do |product_feature| %>
        <%= render 'product_feature_fields', f: product_feature %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <%= link_to_add_association 'Add a new feature', f, :product_features %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="well product-well">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <%= f.fields_for :product_usecases do |product_usecase| %>
        <%= render 'product_usecase_fields', f: product_usecase %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= link_to_add_association 'Add a new usecase', f, :product_usecases %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="well product-well">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <%= f.fields_for :product_competitions do |product_competition| %>
        <%= render 'product_competition_fields', f: product_competititon %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= link_to_add_association 'Add a new competition', f, :product_competitions %>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: you don't by any chance have your view off-hand do you?

Comment: I've updated my question. No js code yet.

Answer (score 1):

It was a weird validation problem. I used to have `product.usecase` attribute then decided to change it to `product_usecase` model and forgot to take out the validation (`product.usecase` must be present) from the product model.